# Rotate UIImageView of UITableViewCell using UIViewAnimation (My app hangs !!)

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiimageview, uiviewanimation

I have this `UITableViewCell` in a table with left `imageView` set to an image. Now all I want is continuously rotate this image when user selects the cell (alias row). I'm able to animate the cell `imageView` to rotate but application stops responding to user inputs once I does so. In other words application hangs and the image rotating as it should be. Below is the relevant code snippet.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)aTableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
//...
    [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(rotateImage) toTarget:self withObject:nil];

//...
}

- (void) rotateImage {
    UITableViewCell *selectedCell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow]];

    [UIView beginAnimations:@"looping animation" context:nil];
    // other animation options here if you'd like, and the duration can be anything, not just 3.

    [UIView animateWithDuration:10 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat animations: ^{
        // do your rotation stuff on your image, in this block, for the cell you will be returning.
        selectedCell.imageView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(kDegreesToRadians(90));
    } completion:nil];

    [UIView commitAnimations];  
}
```

If I comment the `NSThread` code line, application doesn't hang so basically I did something wrong in the animation code only that made the app go in hang state.

Answer (score 1):

The (annoying) default with block animations is to disable user interaction. Try this:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:10 delay:0
                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat|UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction
                 animations:^{
                    selectedCell.imageView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI);
                }
                 completion:NULL];
```